# How are differently sized huge pages allocated to applications in Linux?

Tags: linux, oracle, linux-kernel, oraclelinux

I'm working with a software that runs on an Oracle backend database, which means I get to configure the database VMs infrastructure. Not my specialty, but it is what it is.

My workload is going to be processing tables spanning < 1Mb - ~10Gb (up to 1-2 billion rows with 8 fields), mostly OLAP oriented with lots of parallel reads and bulk inserts of 10k+ rows via jdbc.

I've read that huge pages are important in this context, so I am looking into setting them up; unfortunately, the recommended size and ratio of the huge pages isn't well described online. I can go for either 1 Gb or 2 Mb sized huge pages, or both. My node has 500 Gb in total for the database.

On to my question: If I prepared, e.g., 100 huge pages of size 1 Gb each and 500 huge pages of size 2 Mb each, is there a rhyme or reason for which size of huge page gets allocated when?

1. For example, would the 1 Gb huge pages be allocated until exhaustion, and then the 2 Mb allocated?
2. Or is there any optimization by the kernel as to which size huge page gets used first? Like maybe if the buffer size doesn't exceed the size of the huge page, it won't request it.

Honestly, I am not even sure whether it matters. Just trying to get a feel for how precise I need to be here.

OS: Oracle Linux Server 7.9

DB: Oracle 19.15 EE

Comment: This is probably better a question for the Database Administrators site. I don't have an answer on mixing page sizes. We've only ever used 2MB page sizes around here, with SGAs comparable to what you're envisioning. I do know that unless you force it to use only huge pages, Oracle will allocate what it can from huge pages and any amount of `sga_max_size` above that it will create a second shared segment from normal memory to reach the total demanded. Ideally you want the entire SGA in a single segment in huge pages. But remember you need normal memory for PGA so don't overallocate huge pages!

Comment: "_How are differently sized huge pages allocated to applications in Linux?_": Applications usually must request the huge pages (including their size) themselves. (See e.g. relevant flags in [`man mmap`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html).) So the answer will be application-specific. As an exception the mechanism of [_transparent huge pages_](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/next/admin-guide/mm/transhuge.html) exists where the kernel tries to collapse pages into huge pages. You can see details in the link. However, that's suboptimal and I expect a database to not rely on it.

Comment: Keep in mind that a warehouse-style system with billion+ row tables with lots of parallel full table scans and aggregations will be very light on buffer demand and very heavy on PGA demand. Therefore you can work against yourself by allocating too much to huge pages for the SGA - you aren't likely to need much of an SGA. What you *will* need is plenty of free/free mem on the OS for on-demand PGA workarea allocations for those big sorts and hash joins, especially with high DOPs. I would suggest starting modest, with a PGA in the neighborhood of 10G-50G, and leave the rest for PGA.

Comment: @PaulW Thanks for the tip. The architecture is a bit legacy, and the heavy lifting regarding aggregations etc. is handled by a dedicated warehouse solution. The data pipeline is duplicated for both the warehouse and Oracle, with Oracle currently relegated to serving as a backup / archive system, as the software scripts for the data model are still defined for Oracle. The warehouse resyncs with Oracle regularly to update the datamodel or practically as a backup restore. This means Oracle just needs to sustain bulk inserts for data ingestion / parallel full table scans for resyncs.

Comment: @PaulW Currently I've set quite a bit of PGA, but I am following the advisories in the AWR reports for both SGA and PGA. I've read the buffer hit % isn't reliable as a metric, so even though it's at 50-55% in the AWR, I don't know if it means anything. I thought paging could be worthwhile though since it's recommended.

Comment: If you are just using Oracle as a backup data store, you need neither a large SGA nor much PGA. Those direct path inserts and parallel FTS's will bypass the buffer cache so the SGA won't be doing much for you, and if you aren't querying it other than a straight dump of a table, you won't need much PGA either. Don't waste 500GB on such a database, it could go to better use for some other purpose. And you're right, ignore cache-hit ratios, they are pretty much useless.

Comment: @PaulW Ah I hadn't realized the direct path inserts bypassing the buffer cache would also mean the huge pages wouldn't do much either. The DB is pretty oversized; it's true. I'm stuck with a huge DB because it's running on the cloud, and I can't get a lot of cores without ordering a bigger node, which always comes with a ton of ram, nor do I have other workloads that can significantly share the node RAM without risking siphoning some of its cores away.

Comment: You don't need that many cores for what you're doing. You'll probably be I/O bound as it is, unless you're using basic compression. If it's non-compressed or Exadata with offloaded HCC compression, your compute node CPUs will have relatively little to do simply writing and reading from a single table. Think a number more like 8 or 16 rather than dozens or hundreds.